# Web Development receiving user data

Tags: java, web, server

I would like to create a form using HTML and once the user presses a "submit" button on the web, I can somehow view their results? how would I do that in java. I understand that I would need HTML and CSS to create the front end, but how would I deal with the backend? Thank you all so much

Comment: Request you to learn JSP/Servlet or any of the Java Web frameworks like Struts, Spring, JSF etc...

Comment: Front end development is quite different from server side. Have fun learning!  https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

in most simple pattern that i suggest you to learn

①jsp, servlet, sql

②some web application server knowledge(ex Tomcat)

③some DataBase knowledge(ex MySql)

④perhaps better to know MVC Design Model

Comment: No one said anything about SQL or a database, just getting a POST request

Comment: hwhong said he want anyway to view the submitted results. perhaps he need to store the results and usually a database is Indispensable in our system i think.

Comment: I agree, but it's not necessary for the question

Comment: would it be much better if I just learn php and mysql? Thank you all for the response btw!